# Difference between Systemctl and service command

Tags: apache, ubuntu, service, systemctl

I always run my Apache server in this way:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

But in many guides I saw commands like this:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Can somebody shortly write the difference between these commands and give me advice about what command I should use in everyday work?

Comment: [Difference between Systemctl and Service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`service` operates on the files in */etc/init.d* and was used in conjunction with the old init system. `systemctl` operates on the files in */lib/systemd*. If there is a file for your service in */lib/systemd* it will use that first and if not it will fall back to the file in */etc/init.d*.
Also If you are using OS like ubuntu-14.04 only service command will be available.

So if *systemctl* is available ,it will be better to use it

Comment: According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903405/790184), `service` is a wrapper for all three init systems (/init, systemd and upstart).

Comment: Dan Swain is right. `service` is a wrapper, and thus its preferable over `systemctl` that works only if you have an `apache` service configuration in `/etc/systemd/system/`

Comment: Also note the syntax difference between two commands, ```sudo service <service_name> <action>``` and ```sudo systemctl <action> <service_name>```

Answer (score 27):

With borrowing from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/867334/456328):

> `service` is an "high-level" command used for `start`, `restart,` `stop` and `status`
> services in different *Unixes* and *Linuxes*. Depending on the
> "lower-level" service manager, service redirects on different
> binaries.
>
> For example, on *CentOS 7* it redirects to systemctl, while on *CentOS 6*
> it directly called the relative  `/etc/init.d` script. On the other
> hand, in older Ubuntu releases it redirects to upstart.
>
> `service` is adequate for basic service management, while directly
> calling `systemctl` give greater control options.

Moreover, `systemctl` runs services file from this path: `/lib/systemd/`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to "vote to close" as a duplicate instead of copy/pasting another answer?

Comment: @rinogo This is not just a copy/paste. Actually, it is a kind of reference and quote as specified. The given scores for this answer also indicate that this answer has been needed in this gap place. Keep in mind our aim is to ease and solve askers' issues as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Service started as a helper script for sysvinit an latter became a wrapper script that works regardless of having sysvinit or systemd.

Answer (score 1):

For my choice `service` is more reliable, especially in automatization tasks. It's wrapping commands for different init systems, thus you can use it for older distributions and expect the same result. And in my observation there is often no working `reload` command (update daemon config without process killing ) for systemd unit, when it works with `service <service-name> reload` normally.