# mariadb not starting and getting redirected(AWS- EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, systemctl

```
I am New to AWS
Created a Cloud9 Environment: AWS-EC2
Executed the following command in the environment and mariadb doesnot start. Can anybody 
say why it failed:
```

edXDeployingUser:/ $ sudo service mariadb start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mariadb.service

Comment: what error do you get? The "redirection" is not an error. Read about `init` and `systemd` for this redirection. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537851/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-command#:~:text=service%20operates%20on%20the%20files,file%20in%20%2Fetc%2Finit. too.

Comment: Are you trying to install maria db on the cloud9 shell? or are you trying to create an RDS maria db instance?

Comment: My service mariadb was running - you were right sir (redirection was not an error).