# Program execution with crontab

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04

### Hardware setup (computer, etc)

- **Ubuntu server 18.04.1**
- **Serial To Usb Converter with 8 ports**

### Python version

- **2.7.15r1**

### Python program description

When the program starts to create some threads:

1. Create one thread for the Modbus server.
2. Run 1 thread for each serial port connected (`/dev/ttyUSBn`) and start read the data.

### Problem explanation

When I run the script using the **normal command** (`python2.7 myProgram.py`) it work, so the modbus server start and I can read the value, and I can also see the **usb-serial convert blink on the TX-RX** leds. 
If I check the readed data they are correct, so the program is working properly.

The problem come out when I set up a crontab job that run my python script!

The modbus server start properly, but I can't see the usb-serial converter leds blink and the python program don't print the readed data. That means the program is not working on the "serial" side.

To create the job I has used the following commands:

1. `crontab -e`
2. selected nano (default option)
3. added at the end of the file the cron command: `@reboot /usr/bin/python2.7 /myProgram.py`

I can't figure out where the problem is, the program is not catching the exception and the process is still running until I stop it manually. If I stop it and run it manually after that it start and work properly.

### ***To help you:***

**I have also tried to run it using `**systemctl**`, the problem is the same.
At boot the service start and if I check it I can read: `Active(running)`, but the software is not reading from the serial port.**

The questions are:

- *How can I solve it?*
- *There is something wrong with the crontab job?*
- *Maybe crontab job can't access the /dev/ directory? How can I solve this?*

I'm very confused about that, I hope the question is properly created and formatted.

---

### EDIT 30/11/18:

---

I have removed the crontab command, and create a service to run the program using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735934/running-python-script-as-a-systemd-service/51242883#51242883) procedure.

If I run the command: `service supervision start` I can see that the process is running correctly and on `htop` I have only 4 processes.

[image: htop output]

[image: service status output]

In this case, the program is not reading from the serial port, but the modbus server is working. You can see that I have just 4 processes and the cpu load is too high.

If I run it manually with the command: `python2.7 LibSupervisione.py`

The output of the `htop` command is:
[image: outupt of working program]

Here you can see that I have more processes, 1 for each thread that I create and the load on the cpu is properly distributed.

Comment: Change to `... myProgram.py >>/tmp/myProgram.log 2>&1`, to get the error message and read [crontab-not-running-my-python-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-running-my-python-script)

Comment: Add this `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang on top of your code, and set `chmod 755`  to your code, but the best way is that you create a service from your code, I using from [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242883/3702377) for that.

Comment: @stovfl I have tryed to add the `>>/tmp/myProgram.log 2>&1` in my crontab command, but nothing where printed in the file. As I told the problem is non that the cron job isn't running, but the problem is that it run, start just a piece of program. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: @BenyaminJafari I have tryed to create the service using systemctl, I'll try with your guide! At the top of the file I alredy have `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` and I have updated the permission of the folder to **777** using this command: `chmod 777 /programFolder/ -R`

Comment: @CarloZanocco Could you run your script using a service?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari I have tested it now. The service start correctly but nothing change. I have tryed to run it manually and it work, if I check the processes with `htop` I can see that there a many processes, 1 for each thread(15 processes), and the core are correctly used by the program! If I run `htop` when the program start from the service, the program use just 1 core and I can see only 3 processes so 3 threads running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script probably requires a Console or some Environment variables, but in a systemd started process you dont have these automatically.

The easiest way would be to prepend `/usr/bin/bash -c "your command"` in your System unit in the field `ExecStart` to enable a Shell like Environment likle this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python2.7 /myProgram.py" 

WorkingDirectory=yourWorkingDir
```

Why do you Need to use cron? Use a systemd timer instead.

Comment: I don't need to use cron, I have tested it, because the problem persist with systems, systemctl, service and cron command. I have created a service and the problem persist. The program **START** but is not reading from the serial port, but the modbus server is working.

Comment: Did you start your program with a prepended Shell? Like bash? I know this problem from own experience.

Comment: What it means? Sorry but I don't know what you mean with prepended Shell.. 

I log in to the remote computer using ssh root@ip, after that I use the shell of the Ubuntu Server computer

Comment: you are right. I understand what you mean! But in the script I have to read one config file. I have the path that is not absolute! In the program I have : ` path = "Utility/config.txt" `, but this is wrong, because the folder is in another folder, so the path is not absolute. The correct way is to use: `path = "/Monitoraggio/Utility/config.txt"`. So I have to start from the `/` directory!

Comment: Try to Change the systemd unit to:

``
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python2.7 /myProgram.py"
WorkingDirectory=yourWorkingDir
``

Answer (score 1):

If you could run your code with the service like this: `sudo service <service-name> start` and get a good status using `sudo service <serivice-name> status`, you can test it in `crontab -e` like this (run every 5 minutes for test):

```
*/5 * * * * service <service-name> start
*/10 * * * * service <service-name> stop
```

Then using `@rebote` after with the above test.

---

OR:

Finally, if you want to run your code/service at the system startup, do it instead of `cron jon`:

Edit the `rc.local` file with an editor with the `sudo` permission, then:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.


service <service-name> start

exit 0
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

[This is the procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735934/running-python-script-as-a-systemd-service/51242883#51242883) of creating a `service` from your code.

Comment: The problem is still here. The process is running correctly in any case, I always have a good status. But the problem is that the program not work the same as when I run it manually! 

Using `service test start` it run, I have a good status, but the serial port is not reading in any case. And the server Modbus is working correctly. If I run the code manually with `python2.7 myProgram.py` it work and read from the serial port.

Comment: I have added more info to the question, check the edit please

Comment: I did it, please put on your code for better sense.

Comment: I can't put on the code, I can create a sample code to share with you. But why you need it? The code is working correctly, as I told if I run it not as service it work.

Comment: Don't use this, why start initd from system when you can call it directly.

Comment: @comrad Because in the title of question mentioned "running program not working in crontab", so to overcome it, service is a better way rather than direct running, because it produces `start`, `restart`, `stop` and `status` ...

Comment: @CarloZanocco OK, no problem if you don't want to put on your code. Is your problem that when you run the code by serivce, usb-serial led does not blink? Did you try add the root permision on your usb port using `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB*`?