# Python script not writing to config when run as a systemctl service

Tags: python, service, raspbian, configuration-files, configparser

I'm running a python 3 program on raspbian that must write a string value to a config file. 
I manage to write to config within the main script, but not within the "secondary" one.

-> When debugging in VS code (remote debugger), the secondary script correctly writes to config.txt.

-> When running as a service with `sudo systemctl start myservice` or `su -c 'systemctl start myservice'`, the secondary script doesn't write to config.txt.

In both cases, the program runs to the end with no exception.

**/home/pi/project/my-script.py**

```
# This is the main script. 
# If I move the configWrite method in this one, it writes correctly to config.

from lib import *

def main():
    secondary.authenticate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**/home/pi/project/lib/secondary.py**

```
# This is the script which can't write to config.

import configparser
import logging
import requests

config = configparser.ConfigParser()   
configFilePath = r'/home/pi/project/config.txt'
config.read(configFilePath)
cfg = config['main']
sid = cfg['sid']

def configWrite(field, value):
    config.set('secondary', field, value)
    with open(configFilePath, 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

def authenticate():
    authenticate_url = '...'
    headers = { ... }
    try:
        response = requests.post(authenticate_url, headers=headers, timeout=(30, 10))
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as err:
        logging.warning('Error occurred: {}'.format(err))
        return False
    else:
        global sid
        sid = response.json()['sid']
        configWrite('sid', str(sid))
        return True
```

**/home/pi/project/config.txt** (chmodded to 666)

```
[main]
someitem = foo

[secondary]
sid = bar
```

**/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My service description
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u my-script.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/project
StandardOutput=Inherit
StandardError=Inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Similar question here but with no valid answer : [running python script as a systemd service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735934/running-python-script-as-a-systemd-service)
- I can see that the service runs properly to the end of the script by checking the logs (logging works just fine either way)
- No error in journalctl
- I rebooted the raspberry pi already
- Python version 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you never set the config['main'] to your new value.
Try in configWrite(field, value): config['main'] = {field: value} and then write it to your config.txt like bevor.

Comment: That line was lost when paste-editing code for stackoverflow. I edited the question. Sorry for that

Comment: Then I would try to add the absolut path for the scipt at ExecStart. That solved the problem for me. Like ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/project/my-script.py

Comment: Nope, the script is still not writing to config

Comment: I guess the requests import was also lost while copying?
Have you tried to run the service as root?

Comment: I edited the question to restore the requests import. I also tried the su command (which unfortunately produces the same result as the sudo command)